# In Vala, why node->set_content doesn't accept the ampersand charater?

Tags: libxml2, vala

The following code

```
Xml.Node* node = new Xml.Node (null, "name");
node->set_content("&");
```

produces the following error:

**error : unterminated entity reference**

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Both the greater and less than characters work fine. Also, the add_content method works fine with the ampersand character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

The latter.  From the [xmlNodeSetContent](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeSetContent) documentation: "content is supposed to be a piece of XML CDATA, so it allows entity references, but XML special chars need to be escaped first...".  You can use [GLib.Markup.escape_text](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Markup.escape_text.html) to do so.

> Also, the add_content method works fine with the ampersand character.

From the [xmlNodeAddContent](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeAddContent) documentation: "In contrast to xmlNodeSetContent(), @content is supposed to be raw text, so unescaped XML special chars are allowed, entity references are not supported."